# VBA code to change sources for PivotTables with large volume of data

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I'm searching for the solution to the following problem: I have a workbook with multiple pivot tables and some of them are rather big (46 000 rows +). Now I need to updated them: change the source to the current one for all pivot tables and refresh them. So, I've created a VBA code which is designed to solve my problem. Nevertheless, my datasource for the pivot tables is very large file with xlsb format (800 000 rows and 42 columns) and it's uploaded to the sharepoint. That is why my question is: is it possible to optimize my vba macro to be faster as it takes 40 + minutes or even more to updated all these pivot tables? Maybe I should look at another solution like power pivot?

Below there is a code for the macro

```
Sub Change_Pivot_Source()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim month As Variant
Dim monthname As Variant
Dim yr As Variant

month = Format(Now(), "mm")
monthname = WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "[$-en-US]mmm;@")
yr = Format(Now, "yyyy")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableAnimations = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'https://sharepoint.com/sites/Shared Documents/"Worksheetname " & month & "_" & monthname & " yr & "TotalData.xlsb]Sheet 1'!R2C1:R800000")
Next pt
Next ws

MsgBox ("Source was changed for all pivot tables")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableAnimations = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the source for all the pivot tables the same?  It's not clear from your posted code since the `SourceData` looks incorrectly-formatted...   If it's the same then you should be able to create the PivotCache outside of the loop.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes the source for all pivots is the same. The link is just an example, I have a correctly formated version. How i can make pivotcache outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one source then try just creating a single pivot cache outside of the loop.

```vb
Sub Change_Pivot_Source()

    Dim pt As PivotTable, pc As PivotCache
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim month As Variant
    Dim monthname As Variant
    Dim yr As Variant
    
    month = Format(Now(), "mm")
    monthname = WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "[$-en-US]mmm;@")
    yr = Format(Now, "yyyy")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableAnimations = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
                (SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                 SourceData:="'https://sharepoint.com/sites/Shared Documents/"Worksheetname " & _
                 month & "_" & monthname & " yr & "TotalData.xlsb]Sheet 1'!R2C1:R800000")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
             pt.ChangePivotCache pc
    Next pt
    Next ws
    
    MsgBox ("Source was changed for all pivot tables")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableAnimations = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: After ~30 seconds gives an error: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. Clicking Debug refres to the code pt.ChangePivotCache pc

Comment: I guess I'm unsure how your pivot tables are set up - after your previous code completes how many pivot caches are there in the workbook?   `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count` should tell you that.  Some relevant info here: https://www.contextures.com/xlpivot11.html